# KILL "Android.process.xxx" processes

Tags: android, adt, kill-process

It is possible to kill "Android.process.xxx" system processes programmatically WITHOUT root permissions (e.g. "Android.process.media")? By the way I'm trying to develop (with ADT v21.1) an app with such function.

Comment: If you just wanted to get rid of android.process.media, there is a workaround (worked for me): go to Settings > Apps > All, find "Media Storage", tap on it, "Disable", "Force stop". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can with public void  killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)

but you need to have the permission for that

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />`

Comment: `android.process.media` is unlikely to be killable by this means, as that's not an app.

Comment: So you say "android.process.media" cannot be killed by app?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You can only kill a process that has the same `userID` as the one that is doing the killing.

Comment: Even if user has root permisions?

Comment: If your device is rooted and your app has root privilege then you can kill any process.